# initWithDelegate issues - Blackraccoon

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp, blackraccoon

I am using a package called BlackRaccoon to upload files to an FTP server. I'm really struggling with a really basic delegation concept that I just cant figure out.

In my uploading class .m file, I have a method which calls the BlackRaccoon uploading request. I use the following code:

```
uploadFile = [BRRequestUpload initWithDelegate: self];

uploadFile.path = @"/filehere.txt";
uploadFile.hostname = @"xxx";
uploadFile.username = @"xxx";
uploadFile.password = @"xxx";

//we start the request
[uploadFile start];
```

And in my .h file i have the following:

```
@interface myClass : NSObject <BRRequestDelegate>
{
BRRequestCreateDirectory *createDir;
BRRequestDelete * deleteDir;
BRRequestListDirectory *listDir;

BRRequestUpload *uploadFile;

NSData *uploadData;

}
```

Every time I compile and run, I get an error somewhere in the BlackRaccoon files such as:

> __25-[BRStreamInfo openRead:]_block_invoke [Line 190] No response from the server. Timeout.

On sourcing this error, I find myself in the method creating the read stream, particularly:

```
    request.didOpenStream = NO;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, timeout * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_local_queue(), ^{
    if (!request.didOpenStream && request.error == nil)
    {
        InfoLog(@"No response from the server. Timeout.");
        request.error = [[BRRequestError alloc] init];
        request.error.errorCode = kBRFTPClientStreamTimedOut;
        [request.delegate requestFailed: request];
        [request.streamInfo close: request];
    }
});
```

I am totally flunked by this. Our server is up and running and has no timeout issues with our android devices or apps such as 'FTP Sprite'.

Im pretty sure the issue lies with the initWithDelegate stuff. I just dont think im delegating correctly, but Im not sure why. Does anybody have any ideas? I know I am in need of (id)init somewhere, but I just dont understand where or how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just checked the uploadFile function at [BlackRaccoon](https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon) Git, and I found that in their example, they don't `alloc` a BRRequestUpload object, but call it like this :

```
uploadFile = [BRRequestUpload initWithDelegate: self];
```

Might this be the cause of your crash?

Comment: Apologies - my code did originally have that and I received the 'No known class method for selector 'initWithDelegate'. I had changed it last night and forgot. The lack of known class method was the issue.

Comment: I don't know that framework, but `init` without `alloc` looks plain wrong to me.

Comment: It is wrong. This is a typo in the documentation (which has been corrected). The sample code is correct, however. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I am getting stream connection timeout server no response please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Please make one line change in `BRRequest.m` file.

In `- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<BRRequestDelegate>)aDelegate` Function.
Change

```
self.passiveMode = YES;
```

to

```
self.passiveMode = NO;
```

And it will work....

That change worked for me.